# How I can get json array into php file after post form

Tags: php, json

I have login form

```
  <form class="form-std" method="POST" id="connexion-form" action="https://some-server/auth">
    <input type="text" name="username"  />
    <input type="password" name="password" />
    <input type="submit" value="Ok"/> 
  </form>
```

After submit I have new html page https://some-server/auth with json

```
{"statusMessage":"Some Message","statusCode":"Ststus code"}
```

How I can get json array into php file, and better without going to html page? I need depending on the status code, do something in my php.

Comment: nitpick: that's a json-encoded object, not an array. and if that url spits out json, then likely it's not something you're supposed to be submitting to directly. you submit to a php script on your server, then that script uses curl to hit the url.

Comment: Server scripts that return JSON are usually intended to be used from AJAX, not as the target of a form.